# Why are form fields being reset with viewstate enabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I have a simple asp.net webform with a few text boxes and check boxes. I am using a custom validator for my validation. The problem is when there is a validation error it does not keep the users selected check box options.

At the top of the page I have enabled viewstate and have verified that is enabled by looking at the generated html code.

Isn't viewstate supposed to store that information, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I think you're going to need to show some code, as its a custom validator, for us to help you.

Comment: Please put up some example code.  View state isn't "magic" it works when used correctly and doesn't when there is a problem, just like everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see why... For the check boxes I used regular Html check boxes instead of the server control ones.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing any setup in code behind?

If you're posting back for the validation you could be overwriting things in the view state.

Comment: Yep - watch your .IsPostBack checks!